# How to disable tab stops on the main web page when a snackbar is displayed

Tags: html, javascript

I have a web page with several drop-downs, input fields and buttons that can be accessed with the tab key and the mouse.

When some data is entered, I display a snackbar (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp) with e.g. three buttons.

To prevent that you can click on the drop-downs, input fields and buttons on the main page, I put a `<DIV>` over the whole web page (width: 100% / height: 100%).

But with the tab key the drop-downs, input fields and buttons on the main web page are still accessible.

How can I temporarily disable the tab stops on the main web page so that the focus remains only on the three buttons of the snackbar when the tab key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution.
I added a `<DIV>` with a 'tabindex' with a lower number than the first button on the snackbar and a `<DIV>` with a 'tabindex' with a higher number than the last button on the snackbar and when one of these `<DIV>` gets the focus, I just set the focus back to the buttons on the snackbar.